# Cloud Functions: callback is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

According to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background

> You use background functions when you want to have your Cloud Function invoked indirectly in response to an event, such as a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic, a change in a Cloud Storage bucket, or a **Firebase event**.

And the function paramaters are `(data, context, callback)`: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters

However, when I write a simple function like

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
.document(path)
.onWrite((change, context, callback) => {

   callback()
   return
})
```

I get an error that says

> TypeError: callback is not a function

Is `callback` not part of Firestore background functions? The documentation says it is

If not, is there anyway to immediately exit a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase API is different than the Google Cloud API.  What you linked to was the Cloud API, which accepts a callback parameter.  The Firebase API which you are actually using does not.  The Firebase API for background functions requires you to return a promise that resolves after all the work is complete.  There is no callback to call in that case.

Comment: Thanks. What type of event is it referring to when it says "or a Firebase event"?

Comment: An event represents something that happened in a Firebase or Google Cloud product.

Comment: Okay so for everyone looking at this, don't use the Firebase example they give on the Firebase page, callbacks don't work. Use `return null` instead of `callback()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#set_an_end_condition_to_avoid_infinite_retry_loops